# Theano multiple tensors as output

Tags: python, neural-network, theano

I am using Theano to create a neural network, but when I try to **return two lists of tensors at the same time in a list** I get the error:

```
#This is the line that causes the error
#type(nabla_w) == <type 'list'>
#type(nabla_w[0]) == <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
backpropagate = function(func_inputs, [nabla_w, nabla_b])

TypeError: Outputs must be theano Variable or Out instances. Received [dot.0, dot.0, dot.0, dot.0] of type <type 'list'>
```

What kind of Theano structure should I use to return the two tensors together in an array so I can retrieve them like this:

```
nabla_w, nabla_b = backpropagate(*args)
```

I tried using some of the things I found in the [basic Tensor functionality page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html) but none of those work. (For example I tried the stack or stacklists)

Here is the error I get using theano.tensor.stack or stacklists:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
Apply node that caused the error: Join(TensorConstant{0}, Rebroadcast{0}.0, Rebroadcast{0}.0, Rebroadcast{0}.0, Rebroadcast{0}.0)
Inputs shapes: [(), (1, 10, 50), (1, 50, 100), (1, 100, 200), (1, 200, 784)]
Inputs strides: [(), (4000, 400, 8), (40000, 800, 8), (160000, 1600, 8), (1254400, 6272, 8)]
Inputs types: [TensorType(int8, scalar), TensorType(float64, 3D), TensorType(float64, 3D), TensorType(float64, 3D), TensorType(float64, 3D)]
Use the Theano flag 'exception_verbosity=high' for a debugprint of this apply node.
```

A little extra context to the code:

```
weights = [T.dmatrix('w'+str(x)) for x in range(0, len(self.weights))]
biases = [T.dmatrix('b'+str(x)) for x in range(0, len(self.biases))]
nabla_b = []
nabla_w = []
# feedforward
x = T.dmatrix('x')
y = T.dmatrix('y')
activations = []
inputs = []
activations.append(x)
for i in xrange(0, self.num_layers-1):
    inputt = T.dot(weights[i], activations[i])+biases[i]
    activation = 1 / (1 + T.exp(-inputt))
    activations.append(activation)
    inputs.append(inputt)

delta = activations[-1]-y
nabla_b.append(delta)
nabla_w.append(T.dot(delta, T.transpose(inputs[-2])))

for l in xrange(2, self.num_layers):
    z = inputs[-l]
    spv = (1 / (1 + T.exp(-z))*(1 - (1 / (1 + T.exp(-z)))))
    delta = T.dot(T.transpose(weights[-l+1]), delta) * spv
    nabla_b.append(delta)
    nabla_w.append(T.dot(delta, T.transpose(activations[-l-1])))
T.set_subtensor(nabla_w[-l], T.dot(delta, T.transpose(inputs[-l-1])))
func_inputs = list(weights)
func_inputs.extend(biases)
func_inputs.append(x)
func_inputs.append(y)


backpropagate = function(func_inputs, [nabla_w, nabla_b])
```

Comment: By default the ```[some, stuff]``` construction is a python list. If Theano requires an array you may need to use the ```array()``` constructor which (for python 2.x) lives [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html#module-array).

Comment: Forgot to mention that nabla_w and nabla_b are already list. The problem with what I am doing is that it doesn't accept list of lists of tensors.

Comment: This should work if done correctly (I use this often). Unfortunately the code is not self contained, so I can't figure out what may have gone wrong. Could you provide a minimal example that one can copy and paste, for analysis? Otherwise you will have to rely on the very few people in this forum that already know what must have happened from the error message.

Comment: I just added some extra code for context but i don't think it is easy to have a "copy-pasteable" portion for this, but I will try to change it later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not supported by Theano. When you call `theano.function(inputs, outputs)`, outputs can be only 2 things:

1) a Theano variable
2) a list of Theano variables

(2) does not allow you to have a list in the top level list, so you should flatten the lists in the outputs. This will return more then 2 outputs.

A compossible solution to your problem is to have the inner list copied into 1 variable.

```
tensor_nabla_w = theano.tensor.stack(*nabla_w).
```

This asks that all elements in nabla_w is are the same shape. This will add an extra copy in the computation graph (so it could be a little slower).

Update 1: fix call to stack()

Update 2:

As of now, we have the added constraint that all the elements will have different shapes, so stack can not be used. If they all have the same number of dimensions and dtype, you can use [typed_list](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/typed_list.html), otherwise you will need to modify Theano yourself or flatten the output's lists.

Comment: I mention that i tried stack and stacklist theano.tensor.stack() and I can't find theano.stack() but correct me if i 'm wrong. Also unfortunately the tensors in nabla_w are not of the same shape since neural network neurons per layer vary. I am adding the error message i am getting when using tensor.stack()

Comment: I edited my answer yesterday to tell how you could make it work with different shapes with typed list. But they need to have the same number of dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the comment (I didn't check it before) I will try the typed list and report back!