# PyMC3 TypeError: Outputs must be theano Variable or Out instances

Tags: python, typeerror, theano, pymc3, python-theano

I’m trying to run the `PyMC` demonstration notebook about DPMMs: [Dirichlet process mixtures for density estimation — PyMC3 3.10.0 documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/dp_mix.html)

After getting the version PyMC3 right (v3.9.0), when I run the following code cell from the above notebook linked above:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    alpha = pm.Gamma("alpha", 1.0, 1.0)
    beta = pm.Beta("beta", 1.0, alpha, shape=K)
    w = pm.Deterministic("w", stick_breaking(beta))

    tau = pm.Gamma("tau", 1.0, 1.0, shape=K)
    lambda_ = pm.Gamma("lambda_", 10.0, 1.0, shape=K)
    mu = pm.Normal("mu", 0, tau=lambda_ * tau, shape=K)
    obs = pm.NormalMixture(
        "obs", w, mu, tau=lambda_ * tau, observed=old_faithful_df.std_waiting.values)
```

The TypeError:

````
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-28-3e5d2cb5dec6> in <module> 7 lambda_ = pm.Gamma("lambda_", 10.0, 1.0, shape=K) 8 mu = pm.Normal("mu", 0, tau=lambda_ * tau, shape=K) ----> 9 obs = pm.NormalMixture( 10 "obs", w, mu, tau=lambda_ * tau, observed=old_faithful_df.std_waiting.values 11 )```
…
~/anaconda3/envs/ve1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/theano/compile/function/pfunc.py in rebuild_collect_shared(outputs, inputs, replace, updates, rebuild_strict, copy_inputs_over, no_default_updates) 223 cloned_outputs.append(Out(cloned_v, borrow=v.borrow)) 224 else: --> 225 raise TypeError( 226 "Outputs must be theano Variable or " 227 "Out instances. Received " + str(v) + " of type " + str(type(v))

TypeError: Outputs must be theano Variable or Out instances. Received Shape.0 of type <class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
````

I receive the same TypeError when trying to run https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/fonnesbeck/Bios366/blob/master/notebooks/Section5_2-Dirichlet-Processes.ipynb when running the following code cell which also is creating a `PyMC3` `model`:

```
with pm.Model() as ss_model:
    
    α = pm.Gamma('α', 1., 1.)
    β = pm.Beta('β', 1, α, shape=K)
    w = pm.Deterministic('w', stick_breaking(β))
    
    μ = pm.Uniform('μ', 0., 300., shape=K)
    obs = pm.Mixture('obs', w, pm.Poisson.dist(μ), observed=sunspot_df.value)
```

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064617/theano-multiple-tensors-as-output) post which has the same error, but it's when working directly with Theano.

Anyone else encounter this and know how to troubleshoot?

Comment: This is just a hunch, but it could be an incompatibility between pymc3 and theano versions. Taking a look at https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/blob/v3.9.0/requirements.txt, I would recommend making sure that you have exactly theano 1.0.4 installed and see if it still happens

Comment: Thanks- I had Theano 1.0.5. However, after downgrading to 1.0.4  the same error was encountered.

Comment: Have you installed theano with pip or with conda? installing theano with pip can be problematic: https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/wiki/Installation-Guide-(Linux) and its difficult to troubleshoot

Comment: installing from conda forge per the instructions resolved the error. i don't think i had installed `theano` individually to begin with, but it's fixed now. if you post this as an answer i'll happily accept it. thanks! for the record, i know have PyMC3 1.11.1 and theano 1.1.2 working the aforementioned notebook.

Comment: Thanks, I myself am glad you managed to get PyMC3 to work, feel free to add the answer yourself so the question is marked as solved